# Queries fail with "invalid column" errors after running EF5 data migrations to a SQL Azure DB

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I modified the user class and created a data migration in Visual Studio 2012's Package Manager Console. The data migration included the following script:

```
            CreateTable(
            "dbo.Users",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Username = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Comment = c.String(),
                    EmailAddress = c.String(maxLength: 64),
                    Identifier = c.String(),
                    IsApproved = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    LastPasswordFailureDate = c.DateTime(),
                    LastActivityDate = c.DateTime(),
                    LastLockoutDate = c.DateTime(),
                    LastLoginDate = c.DateTime(),
                    ConfirmationToken = c.String(),
                    CreateDate = c.DateTime(),
                    IsLockedOut = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LastPasswordChangedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    PasswordVerificationToken = c.String(),
                    PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate = c.DateTime(),
                    PersonId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    OwnerId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    EffectiveDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    ExpirationDate = c.DateTime(),
                    CreationDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    UpdatedDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Creator = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Updater = c.String(nullable: false),
                    AlertConfiguration_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.People", t => t.PersonId, cascadeDelete: false)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AlertConfigurations", t => t.AlertConfiguration_Id)
            .Index(t => t.PersonId)
            .Index(t => t.AlertConfiguration_Id);
```

After running the migration, the User table is successfully created in the database with all the columns indicated. However, subsequent queries to the database generate the following errors:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'OwnerId'.
Invalid column name 'EffectiveDate'.
Invalid column name 'ExpirationDate'.
Invalid column name 'CreationDate'.
Invalid column name 'UpdatedDate'.
Invalid column name 'Creator'.
Invalid column name 'Updater'.
```

The user class inherits from AuditableClass, which is defined like this:

```
public abstract class AuditableClass
    {
        public AuditableClass()
        {
            this.CreationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "An owner ID is required")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Effective Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "An effective date is required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? EffectiveDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Expiration Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "An creation date is required")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A last update date is required")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "An creator is required")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Creator { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "A last updater is required")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public string Updater { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the user class:

```
public class User : AuditableClass
    {
        [Required]
        public virtual String Username { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public virtual String Comment { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        [StringLength(64)]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public string Identifier { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsApproved { get; set; }
        public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastActivityDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastLockoutDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; set; }
        public String ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsLockedOut { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LastPasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
        public String PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public virtual List<myApp.Models.Parties.Org> AuthorizedOrgs { get; set; }
        public virtual List<myApp.Models.Security.Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

The columns that are the subject of the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException are all inherited from the AuditableClass.

How can I get the Entity Framework to recognize the inherited columns?

Comment: Update - I removed the inherited relationship and the errors still persist, even though the "invalid" columns no longer have corresponding attributes in the User class.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was that the User object contains a Roles collection, which was loaded dynamically at runtime when the user was instantiated. The Roles table corresponding to the Role class had also originally been part of the security schema and had been moved to the transactional schema at the same time as the Users table had been moved. The Roles table had been created using the automatic data migration functionality of the Package Manager Console. This functionality had created the table but had missed the inherited columns (Role also inherits from AuditableClass).

Creating a data migration and then entering the code to manually create the columns that the automatic migration had missed solved the problem.

Here is the code for the migration that resolved the problem:

```
    public partial class UpdateRoles : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Roles", "OwnerId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.Roles", "EffectiveDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.Roles", "ExpirationDate", c => c.DateTime());
        AddColumn("dbo.Roles", "CreationDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.Roles", "UpdatedDate", c => c.DateTime(nullable: false));
        AddColumn("dbo.Roles", "Creator", c => c.String(nullable: false, defaultValue: "myusername"));
        AddColumn("dbo.Roles", "Updater", c => c.String(nullable: false, defaultValue: "myusername"));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```